# mysql update HH:MM:SS from an epoch time

Tags: mysql, epoch

I'm looking to do a mass query update on a column that is in ms from the epoch.  For each row returned according to my where clause, I would like to update the time value to something passed in, and have it still stored in ms.  What would my update clause need to look like?

For example, I have two rows

```
MY_TIMESTAMP  | VALUE
----------------------
1281275302000 | some val 1
1347198502000 | some val 2
```

Row 1 corresponds to Sun, 08 Aug 2010 13:48:22 UTC 
Row 2 corresponds to Sun, 09 Sep 2012 13:48:22 UTC

Now I want to set both times, say to 07:00:00, but leave the dates as is.  So the result of the update statement should look like:

```
MY_TIMESTAMP  | VALUE
----------------------
1281250800000 | some val 1
1347174000000 | some val 2
```

corresponding to Sun, 08 Aug 2010 07:00:00 UTC and Sun, 09 Sep 2012 07:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible with only simple math, to avoid any time zone consideration:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET MY_TIMESTAMP = MY_TIMESTAMP - (MY_TIMESTAMP % 86400000) + 25200000
```

`MY_TIMESTAMP - (MY_TIMESTAMP % 86400000)` gives you the date without the time

`25200000` equals 7 hours in milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is better.

Comment: Great solution, thank you.  I was going down a much more complicated path

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using FROM_UNIXTIME:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
  SET MY_TIMESTAMP = (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MY_TIMESTAMP / 1000 + 14400)), '07:00:00')) - 14400) * 1000;
```

Test if it gives you the right result with this select:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MY_TIMESTAMP / 1000 + 14400)), '07:00:00')) - 14400) * 1000 
   FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 100;
```

P.S. 14400 corresponds to my offset from UTC in seconds. If yours is different, change it.